# Mouse Over only on text not on entire row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I provide Mouse hover effect only on text not on entire row. I tried with Position(), But cam out with empty .Below is fiddle link,

```
<ul id='ulid'>
<li>Task1</li>
<li>Task2</li>
<li>Task3</li>
<li>Task4</li>
<li>Task5</li>
<li>Task6</li>
<li>Task7</li>
</ul>

<br /><br />


<br /><br />

<div id="show_details"></div>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {


$('ul#ulid li').hover(function() {
    $('#show_details').html($(this).text());
}, function() {
    $('#show_details').html('');
});
});
```

Please help

Comment: use <span/> inside <li/>

Comment: The guy above me is right. Wrap your text in a <span> and use the hover function on the span.

Answer (score 5):

Your `li` elements can't be block-display.  There are a lot of ways to handle it, but one easy way is just to wrap them with spans and trigger the `.hover` on those spans:

```
<li><span>Task1</span></li>
...
$('ul#ulid li span').hover(function() {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xneG5/

Programatically: http://jsfiddle.net/xneG5/2/

CSS only: http://jsfiddle.net/xneG5/3/

Answer (score 0):

Setting the margins and padding of the li elements to 0 could possibly solve this problem.  The reason it is triggering the entire row is because li comes with default margins and padding.