# Hover effect only on letter (not container)

Tags: javascript, css, svg, hover

I have a huge text and would like to trigger a color change **when the letters are hovered**. This means the white background shouldn't trigger the hover effect, only the black fiill of the letter should trigger it.

The default hover effect is triggered when the text container is hovered like this :

```css
* {margin: 0;padding: 0;}
p {
  font-size: 75vw;
  line-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}
p:hover {
  color: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<p>SO</p>
```

Using the text element in svg acts the same way :

```css
text:hover{
    fill:darkorange;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <text x="0" y="50" font-size="70">SO</text>
</svg>
```

Is there a way to trigger the hover effect only when the **fill of the letters** (black parts in the examples) are hovered and not on the containing box?

Comment: Hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575966/mouse-over-only-on-text-not-on-entire-row

Comment: A solution might be to convert the text to paths, using for example https://github.com/nodebox/opentype.js or https://www.npmjs.com/package/vectorize-text

Comment: I know the map tag but even that will not be handy as the shape is totally unconventional, this is possible may be only through JavaScript. I hope you get the answer, i had thought about this before but didn't had guts to put it here

Comment: Note that depending on the use case you may also convert a text to a path in Inkscape.

Comment: @DeepKakkar I saw that question before asking but it doesn't help as the hover effect is still  triggered on the containing block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Inkscape to [convert the text to a path](https://answers.launchpad.net/inkscape/+question/52430) via Path>Object to path or Path>Stroke to path. Once the text is actually a path hover will by default only operate on the rendered parts of the path.

I.e. you'd need to edit the document itself, it's not something SVG directly supports currently although is is being [considered for the upcoming SVG 2 specification](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/SVG2_Requirements_Input#Consider_adding_a_DOM_method_to_convert_a_.3Ctext.3E_element_to_outline_path_data).

Comment: Thx for the answer. I'll see how I can implement this dynamicaly until that feature is live.

Answer (score 2):

I've had some mixed success with making the letters out of pure CSS (CSS adapted from [CSS Sans](http://yusugomori.com/projects/css-sans/fonts)):

```js
$('span').hover(function(){
    $('.A-after,.A-before').css({
      'background-color':'red',
      'z-index':'99'
    });
  $('.A').css('border-bottom','solid 14px red');
  
},function(){
      $('.A-after,.A-before').css({
      'background-color':'black',
      'z-index':'99'
    });
  $('.A').css('border-bottom','solid 14px #000000');
});
```

```css
.A {
    position:relative;
    left:30px;
    width:60px;
    height:91px;
    border-bottom:solid 14px #000000;
}
.A-before {
    transform:skew(-19deg, 0);
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    top:12.5px;
    left:35px;
    width:16px;
    height:125px;
    background-color:#000000;
}
.A-after {
    transform:skew(19deg, 0);
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    top:12.5px;
    left:78px;
    width:16px;
    height:125px;
    background-color: #000000;
}

span { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span class="A-before"></span>
  <span class="A"></span>
  <span class="A-after"></span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this is what you must have meant by *mixed success* but just in case - Hover effect is triggered when we mouse is over the triangular area within the A and also just outside the triangular area on top. That said, still a very good try :)

Comment: Yep. It all basically comes down to how the letters are drawn that can yield those false positive hover areas. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexW thx for the answer, I had considered this approach and would probably use it if  I only had a few letter and no double curved ones like "S" But I need more letters and this approach would need to much work. BTW why are you using jQuery for the hover effect?

Comment: The jQuery was just purely for rapid prototyping. You could easily use regular JavaScript to re-create what I did above.

Answer (score -1):

This is unconventional, but you could put an `a` around it and target `a:hover`. Then also include a `pointer-event` and `cursor` style.

```
.text a, .text a:link, .text a:visited, .text a:active{
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
text-decoration:none;
}

.text a:hover{
    color:orange !important;
}
```